# Xamarin app crashing without logs just after launch

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have this code that should get info about wifi networks and then, connect to one of them. You will see two parts of the code that are commented, when these parts are commented it works, but putting them to run causes application crash without any logs, doesn't matter if I use try/catch blocks. I know I'm doing some bad practices like putting anything in MainActivity, but this is only for study purposes.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.smfw.switchmyfuckingwifi">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="31" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <application android:label="SwitchMyFuckingWifi.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
        <service android:name=".SwitchMyFuckingWifi" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Net;
using Android.Net.Wifi;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SwitchMyFuckingWifi.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "SwitchMyFuckingWifi", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
            try { Teste(); }
            catch(Exception a) {
                Console.WriteLine("DEU ERRO AQUI => "+a.Message);
            }
        }

        public async override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        
        private WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);

        private Timer timer;
        public void Teste()
        {
            WifiInfo currentWifiInfo = wifiManager.ConnectionInfo;
            if (currentWifiInfo == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*********************" + System.Environment.NewLine + "Nenhuma informações sobre a rede atual" + System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine + "*********************");
                return;
            }
            /*else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("******************************************" + System.Environment.NewLine + "| CONEXÃO ATUAL |" +
                    " Força do sinal: "+currentWifiInfo.Rssi+
                    " SSID da rede: " + currentWifiInfo.SSID +
                    " BSSID da rede: " + currentWifiInfo.BSSID +
                    System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine + "******************************************");

            }*/

            int currentSignalStrength = WifiManager.CalculateSignalLevel(currentWifiInfo.Rssi, 5);

            IList<ScanResult> scanResults = wifiManager.ScanResults;
            if (scanResults == null || scanResults?.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*********************"+ System.Environment.NewLine + "Nenhuma wifi por perto" + System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine + "*********************");
                return;
            }

            ScanResult strongestSignal = null;
            int strongestSignalStrength = int.MinValue;
            foreach (ScanResult result in scanResults)
            {
                int signalStrength = WifiManager.CalculateSignalLevel(result.Level, 5);
                Console.WriteLine("*********************" + System.Environment.NewLine+ System.Environment.NewLine +
                    "Nome da rede: "+result.Ssid +
                    " | Força do sinal: "+result.Level.ToString()
                    + System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine + "*********************" + System.Environment.NewLine);
            }


           MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage>("ThisSub", "change", async (arg1) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("CHEGOU A MENSAGEM");
                    /*WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
                    wifiConfig.Ssid = "xxxxxxx";
                    wifiConfig.PreSharedKey = "PASSWRD";

                    int netId = wifiManager.AddNetwork(wifiConfig);
                    wifiManager.Disconnect();
                    wifiManager.EnableNetwork(netId, true);
                    wifiManager.Reconnect();*/
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROOOOOOOO AQUI => " + e.Message);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("FINALIZOU A MENSAGEM");
            });

        }
    }

}
```

Oh, I almost forget to say that I did give all the permissions manually through the application info page of the android applications options.

UPDATE 1:  **DEVICE LOG**

https://pastebin.com/raw/64ThZAih

At pastebin due to body size limitation.

Comment: "crashing without logs" - unlikely. Have you tried getting the device output using **logcat**? There should almost certainly be some kind of exception or error message showing up in the logs.

Comment: if the exception isn't being caught, you can step through the code in the debugger until you find the line that causes the problem.

Comment: Just a wild guess: maybe wifiManager is set before context is ready to provide that. Variable initializations run as soon as class is loaded; that might be too early. Move the initialization line into OnCreate. Any better?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve no changes when I put wifiManager into OnCreate.

Comment: @ewerspej I just updated the question with the device logs. Please, have a read when you guys have time.

Comment: @Jason I updated the question with the device logs. Please, have a read when you have time.

Answer (score 1):

Your device log is partial and doesn't even contain the log entries for starting your App or where it is reported to be ended by the Android OS, so making a couple of assumptions.

First issue with the code you've provided. You've manually added the manifest entry: `<service android:name=".SwitchMyFuckingWifi" />`. This is not necessary. Instead, on a class inheriting from `Service` you would simply annotate it with `[Service]` and the manifest entry is generated for you. I.e.:

```
[Service]
public class MyWifiService : Service
{
    // code here
}
```

Next issue. It seems like you do not request Location permissions. From Android 9 and up, you now need to request this permission to scan for Wifi, failing to do so, you might end up in methods throwing exceptions because of this.

Actually switching to a specific Wifi network is a bit hard depending on which API level you are running your App on. Good luck with that part. It is much easier pre-Android 9. On Android 10 it is totally broken. Android 11 has a slightly better API but very limited in what you can do unless your App is Device Admin.

Last issue. You've set `android:minSdkVersion="31"` is this actually what you want? What version of Android are you running your App on?